# JAVA_HOME: /bin/java vs /bin/amd64/java

Tags: java, 64-bit, intel, amd-processor, sunos

I am running a 64-bit application in server mode on

```
SunOS box1 5.10 *** i86pc i386 i86pc
```

but somehow script chooses

```
/...some_path.../bin/amd64/java
```

to run it. How does it affect my application? Should I be worried?

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer:** You're okay. The `amd64` directory stores 64-bit x86 code. Since youre running Solaris on a 64-bit x86 CPU, `amd64` is fine.

**Longer Answer:**
The `amd64` directory contains the 64-bit x86 binaries for Java.
The `/bin/java/` directory may be (or contain) a symbolic link to the directory (or binaries) in the `amd64` directory.
Depending on who provided that build of Java, `/usr/bin/java` may actually be a script that does an environment set-up & calls what it thinks are the correct binaries.